# jquery button enabling just in one post

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, textarea

I have a series of posts. Each post has a `textarea` (input text) and a cancel and submit buttons. Initially the submit button is disabled, until some text is written.

Nevertheless, when I first type some text in one `textarea`, all posts submit `button` get enabled and not just the one in the post typing in.

My JavaScript code:

```
  $('.small-textarea').click(function() {

        $('.btn-info').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $(this).addClass("set-large");
        $('.set-large').keyup(function() {
            var $this = $('.set-large');
            if($(this).val() == '') {
               $('.btn-info').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
            else {
              $('.btn-info').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });

  });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="footer-condensed-replies" class="footer-condensed">
    <!--<input class="input-xlarge" type="text" placeholder="Reply to @Gerardo">-->
    <textarea class="small-textarea" type="text" placeholder="Reply to @Gerardo"></textarea>
    <div id="" class="footer">
        <div id="" class="footer-submit-button">
            <button type="button" id="cancel" class="btn" data-value="Cancel">Cancel</button>   <span id="footer-btn-margin"></span>

            <button id="hunch" class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show some HTML, you're going to have to use an instance of `this` to get the closest submit button, but without HTML, we can't help.

Comment: Do Show your markup as well... Your selector is the problem, you need to make it relative.

Comment: Does the `footer-condensed` is repeated. i have added an answer check it out. assuming that section is the one that repeats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your markup this is one way:

Provided your markup is like this:

```
<input type="text" class="small-textarea" />
<input type="button" class="btn-info" value="Submit" />
<br/>
<input type="text" class="small-textarea" />
<input type="button" class="btn-info" value="Submit" />
<br/>
<input type="text" class="small-textarea" />
<input type="button" class="btn-info" value="Submit" />
```

You can do this: Since the button is next to the textbox you will use `.next()` to select and target only that button but not all.

```
$('.small-textarea').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("set-large").next('.btn-info').prop('disabled', true);
});

$(document).on('keyup', '.set-large', function () { // Use another container that holds these elements in instead of document
    $(this).next('.btn-info').prop('disabled', $(this).val() == '');
});
```

- use `prop` instead of `attr`
- Do not register click event inside another event without unbinding, it will end up creating duplicate keyup handlers for your elements. You can use event delegation instead using `.on()` 1.7+ or `.live()` older.
- Use relative target instead of selecting with the classname which can select all of them.

**Update**

With your markup you can do this:

```
$('.small-textarea').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("set-large").next().find('.btn-info').prop('disabled', $(this).val() == '');
});
$(document).on('keyup', '.set-large', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).next().find('.btn-info').prop('disabled', $(this).val() == '');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pgT6d/)**

Comment: @crowdfun cool.... is the element `footer-condensed` exist all the tim e? if so do `$('.footer-condensed').on('keyup', '.set-large', function () {`

Comment: Hey, fireworks too soon :\  I tried out your demo and it works. When I test in mine, it works for the first post. When I write something on the 2nd post textarea, it doesn't enable the Submit button, nor in the follwing posts. Can you help with it?

Comment: is your second post `.small-textarea` added dynamically? Also is the section `'.footer-condensed'` added dynamically? try doing `$(document).on('click','.small-textarea',function(){...`

Comment: Just changed to .footer-condensed and works everything now. Thanks man

Comment: one last question: why to use $(document) instead of the simple selector?

Comment: i.e because we need to bind event on `.set-large` which the class is added dynamically so better way you can do is with event delegation. See my second bullet point in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use prop() instead of attr().... and `$(this).parent().find('.btn-info')` to get the submit button

try this

```
$('.small-textarea').click(function() {

    $('.btn-info').prop('disabled',true);
    $(this).addClass("set-large");
 });

$('.set-large').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
           $(this).parent().find('.btn-info').prop('disabled',true);
        }
        else {
          $(this).parent().find('.btn-info').prop('disabled',false);
        }
    });
```